# How can I push an .net app on heroku without and skip migration?

Tags: c#, heroku, git-push

I'm trying to push an app on heroku but I get the following error:

```
remote:   Migrating Database ...
remote:   /usr/bin/sh: 2: /tmp/tmpe9244f6551c347c0b1c860b62eb73b10.exec.cmd: dotnet-ef: not found
remote: /tmp/build_65356b64/DBot/DBot.csproj(37,3): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet-ef database update" exited with code 127.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Core .NET app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to macarenadbot.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/macarenadbot.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/macarenadbot.git'
```

I have Entity Framework installed globally.

```
PS E:\projects\dbot> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.
```

I've tried everything I could find on the internet but noting worked. Any idea about a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed `dotnet-ef` as a *global* tool:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

[This means](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-install#description) that it was installed to `$HOME/.dotnet/tools/` (Linux or macOS) or `%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools\` (Windows) on your local development machine. Tools installed this way are *not* declared as dependencies for the project.

But Heroku needs all of its dependencies to be declared—that's how it knows what to install!

Re-run without the `--global` flag:

```
dotnet tool install dotnet-ef
```

(Note that you might need to create the manifest first using `dotnet new tool-manifest` if you haven't already done so.)

This will cause the dependency to be captured in your manifest:

> Local tools are added to a *dotnet-tools.json* file in a *.config* directory under the current directory.

Then commit the updated manifest and redeploy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I deleted the migration command from .csproj and I've done migration manually.

Comment: @Gabriel, did you try adding a local dependency as I suggested? This should work.

Comment: I didn't try. The solution was to delete the migration command from .csproj and do migration from Visual studio. I will try your solution at the next deploy. Now i run into another problem, You can see it at the link below, if you have time for an advice :). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73348163/app-is-crashing-on-the-server-because-of-the-port