# app is crashing on the server because of the port

Tags: c#, .net, heroku, port

I have an .NET console app that I've uploaded to heroku server.
After I've pushed the app on the server, the app is running for 60 second and I receive this error in the console:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within
> 60 seconds of launch  State changed from starting to crashed

From what I've read on the internet I should make the app to run on the 0.0.0.0 URL and PORT provided by de server environment, but I have no idea how to do that (I'm a beginner developer).

On heroku website is [this article](https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error) that explains the `PORT` part for Node.js, but I don't know how to apply this to .NET.

Here is my Program.cs:

```
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(x =>
            {
                var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                .Build();
                x.AddConfiguration(configuration);
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsole();
                x.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
            })
            .ConfigureDiscordHost((context, config) =>
            {
                config.SocketConfig = new DiscordSocketConfig
                {
                    
                    LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug,
                    AlwaysDownloadUsers = false,
                    MessageCacheSize = 1000
                };

                config.Token = context.Configuration["token"];
            })
            .UseCommandService((context, config) =>
            {
                config.CaseSensitiveCommands = false;
                config.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug;
                config.DefaultRunMode = RunMode.Sync;
            })
            .UseInteractionService((context, config) =>
            {
                config.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug;
                config.UseCompiledLambda = true;
            })
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services
                .AddHostedService<CommandHandler>()
                .AddScoped<PubgService>()
                //.AddDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Development"))    
                //                                                   .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true))
                .AddDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>(options
                                                => options.UseNpgsql(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")))
                .AddSingleton<DataAccessLayer>();
            })
            .UseConsoleLifetime();

        var host = builder.Build();

        using (host)
        {        
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check connection string and credentials used to connect to database.  It looks like you do not have access to the database from the server.  Do you have a client app that is connecting to the server (http)?  The client credentials may not be correct.  For example a client connecting to a server has by default GUEST privileges which may not have permission to access the database.

Comment: It's a discord bot with a database. I don't have a client. In the first 60 second,  when the app is running,  the database it is working.  Is reading and wrting data.

Comment: Issue has nothing to do with the port since the connection completes.  You need to install the same Runtime version of Core that was used to compile code (see : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet).  You may need to update linux as well.  See following for installation steps : https://dev.to/alrobilliard/deploying-net-core-to-heroku-1lfe

Comment: I guess the server is confused because I uploaded an console app, not an web app. On the link you gave me, the guy that wrote the first comment at the article is having the same problem and solved by setting an environment port.

Comment: You have a two port application.  One port where a client connects to the server and 2nd port where the server connects to the database.  The error is the connection between the server and the database.  Probably due to the credentials that are used for the connection.  The server running by itself normally starts with a System Account with no real account associated with the System Account.  So connection to database fails.  For code to run the service would need to be started with an account like Run As XYZ,  But this is not recommended for web apps where a hacker could run service.

Comment: the connection between app and database it's working, I've tested it. The host server is expecting to have an web page. It is trying to access the webpage but it can not, because I don't have an web page/ web app, ! have only an console app.

Comment: The code will work if you are login to server and run because the app has a user account and credentials.  When you run as a service there is no user account and credentials.  The current issue is you are running as a service.  If you add a webpage you will have same issue unless you add authentication.

Comment: there are no credentials. It is just a console app. I can show you on discord if you don't believe me Diablo#2836 is my discord name.